# Castle Windsor: "LoggingFacility.UseNLog() is obsolete"

Tags: .net, logging, castle-windsor, nlog

Long ago, I made a little project wherein I hoped to learn about Castle Windsor.  I put it aside (before really learning all that much) for quite some time.  I just opened it up again now, and updated NuGet packages, and started getting a warning CS0618:

> 'LoggingFacility.UseNLog()' is obsolete: 'A logger factory
>   implementation type should be provided via LogUsing(), this will be
>   removed in the future.'

I've googled based on this, but it's still not clear to me what I am supposed to do in order to replace the now-obsolete call, which is:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseNLog());
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this? https://gist.github.com/dlidstrom/786131
`container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => .LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.NLog).WithConfig("nlog.config"));`

Comment: Thowk, thanks, but yes, I did.  It just doubles the warnings - when I replace my call with that, it says that both LoggingFacility.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation) AND LoggerImplementation are obsolete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oooh, I think I have stumbled upon the answer.  Haven't tested it yet, but the very least, the following does not give any compiler warning:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing<NLogFactory>());
```

Comment: That indeed is the way to go, as pointed out in the documentation https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/logging-facility.md#in-code